# What does this ORM kohana3 query do?

Tags: php, orm, kohana-3

I am unable to interpret this ORM query from the [Kohana 3](http://kohanaframework.org/) ORM framework. Please help me in understanding this:

```
$member_type_id=ORM::factory("member")->where('id',$videos[$count]->member_id)->find();
```

Comment: Just a side-note: for Kohana3 ORM, that won't work. The where method expects 3 parameters: `->where('id', '=', $videos[$count]->member_id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = <$videos[$count]->member_id>
```

The query will return at most one result.

Comment: when i write this query it gives following error message:         $sql = DB::query(Database::SELECT,"select * from member where 'id' = $videos[$count]->member_id);                               ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string